# How to change default view of the lightning-file-upload LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

The standard view of the lightning-file-upload component is the following:

[image]

I would like to change it to just a clip without an ability of droping files. It should look like that:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, as for now **Winter '22** it is not possible to customize `lightning-file-upload` component and set something custom in the slot of the body.

You'll need to build a custom file-upload component and handle  file selection, file saving and all needed events/actions. Use [File Selector](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/file-selector/) SLDS component markup as a starting point for it.